# Apper does not show the installation history anymore

Tags: debian, software-installation, package-management, kde, history

I think the installation history of the GUI Apper is very useful: it shows a history of package installs and removals with timestamps and I think it should also show installations made via the command-line (such as `apt-get install package` recorded in `dpkg.log` files) and I don't know of any other pre-installed GUI in KDE that does that too.

I don't know if this is due to a recent upgrade from Debian11 to 12, but it doesn't show any entries anymore under History which are still shown on another machine. Where is the file of Apper's installation history stored, why did this occur and **how to make it show the installation history again** if it isn't lost?

When running `apper` in the console and opening the History page, it shows `QObject::connect: No such slot PackageKit::Transaction::transaction(QDBusObjectPath,QString,bool,uint,uint,QString,uint,QString)`.